# toggle menu only opens when clicked and and not as default

Tags: javascript

I created a side menu on my website, the only problem is it only opens when I click on button and not as default, In big screens I need it to be always open although in smaller screens I need it to be close and to be able to open it.

my current javascript code is:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#warpper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
});
```

my html:

```
<div id="warpper">


    <!--sidebar-->
        <div id="sidebar-warpper">

        </div>

        <div id="page-content-warpper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="menu-toggle">toggle</a>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</div>
```

Comment: ,more code needed for debugging this

Comment: `#warpper` you mean `#wrapper` ? not only that if you want it open on default add class `menuDisplayed` to `#wrapper`. Then on click just read read width of window. `If` window width is smaller than width`x` then don't toggle class else do toggle class

Comment: I added my html, if you can show me how it has to be done, thanks. @KelvinYe

Comment: @Riddell can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (isBigScreen()){
        $("#warpper").addClass("menuDisplayed");
    }

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#warpper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
        console.log('Hello');
    });
});

var ScreenThreshold = 600;

function isBigScreen(){
    var t = $(window).width();
    console.log(t);
    if (t >= ScreenThreshold){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is okey, but for always open by default you have to add "menuDisplayed" into your wrapper by default. so now your code should be like this.

```
<div id="warpper" class="menuDisplayed">


<!--sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar-warpper">

    </div>

    <div id="page-content-warpper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="menu-toggle">toggle</a>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And also you need this open default only in full screen so you have to remove this class in mobile and then toggle it. so also chnage the jQuery as follow.

```
var w = $(window).width();
if (w < 768) {
   $("#warpper").removeClass("menuDisplayed");
}
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

 $("#warpper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
 });
```